# SSHD HMAC Configuration

Tags: ssh, encryption, terminology, cryptography

I have read and understand the posting from here, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39756/secure-configuration-of-ciphers-macs-kex-available-in-ssh. However, I would like to know what the `/etc/sshd_config` configuration would look like should I want to accomplish the following goals:

- Disable any 96-bit HMAC Algorithms
- Disable any MD5-based HMAC Algorithms

Would it be the following?

> MACs
>   hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160

Note that this question is looking for the configuration setting(s) needed; and not reasons, rationale, or discussion of why this may or may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) says so. Why don't you just try it out ? Setup a SSH server somewhere, with that configuration, and connect to it from another machine with `ssh -vv`: the debug log will show the list of MAC algorithms advertised as supported by the server.

(I read your last sentence as: "I know this is stupid but I don't want to discuss it", which I further interpret as "I am looking for the fastest way to shut some dumb auditors up".)

Comment: yes, this is due to some audits being performed where the network based vulnerability scanner is showing vulnerabilities for "SSH Insecure HMAC Algorithms Enabled." I am looking for a configuration that will satisfy their scans.

Comment: Sounds like nessus. I was just playing around with this, thanks for that!

Comment: man pages are most useful to those who already know how it works (it being whatever the man page is about)... so the "RTFM" portion of the answer isn't terribly helpful.